# Cannot understand the field injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm trying to understand the dependecy injection.

I read many articles but, the more I read, the more I get confused.

So, what I did, is trying to understand some source codes posted on [the Google Guice page](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Motivation).

I understood that we must create a module (ex: `BillingModule`) where the binding between the interface and its implementation is done :

```
bind(BillingService.class).to(RealBillingService.class);
```

And in the implementation class, we must `inject` the constructor.

The problem is that I can't understand [the field injection](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections) :

```
@Inject Connection connection;
```

The question is simple : What does it mean ?

Answer (score 4):

It means you don't instantiate your object as you would normally:

```
Connection connection = //someConstructor
```

but you rather expect to get it through some other means. The
 `@Inject` 
annotation defines an Injection point and it is where you want your application server to instantiate the Connection object for you, depending on configuration. Basically that means you are relieved of the complexities of instantiating the Connection object and can only work on functionality.

Of course, if you application server does not support field injection or for some reason it failed, the @Inject annotation would not mean anything and you will end up with a null connection object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To avoid having the `null` value for that object, what should I do ? Should I create a `Connection` interface and bind it to a `ConnectionIml` implementation class that will contain an `inject` annotation at the top of its constructor ?

Comment: To be honest, I have never seen such practice. Usually if your application server fails to provide you with a proper value for your Connection, you tweak the application server, not write failover code.

Comment: Thanks! made much sense explained so straight forward!

Answer (score 1):

Annotates members of your implementation class (constructors, methods and fields) into which the [Injector](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html) should inject values. The Injector fulfills injection requests for:

- Every instance it constructs. The class being constructed must have
  exactly one of its constructors marked with [`@Inject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) or must have a
  constructor taking no parameters. The Injector then proceeds to
  perform method and field injections.
- Pre-constructed instances passed to [`injectMembers(Object)`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#injectMembers%28java.lang.Object%29),
  [`toInstance(Object)`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/binder/LinkedBindingBuilder.html#toInstance%28T%29) and [`toProvider(Provider)`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/binder/LinkedBindingBuilder.html#toProvider%28com.google.inject.Provider%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29). In this case all
  constructors are, of course, ignored.
- Static fields and methods of classes which any [Module](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Module.html) has
  specifically requested static injection for, using
  [`requestStaticInjection(Class...)`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requestStaticInjection%28java.lang.Class%3C?%3E...%29).

In all cases, a member can be injected regardless of its Java access specifier (private, default, protected, public).

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense